# MySQL WorkBench How to automatically re run query?

Tags: python, mysql

I currently have a Raspberry Pi running Iperf non stop and collecting results.

After collecting results it uploads the bandwidth tests to MySQL.

Is there a way to automatically refresh the table to which the data is added?

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal is to use MySQL workbench to build a live-view of your data ? If so I don't think you're using the right tools.

You may just use ElasticSearch to store your data and Kibana to display it, this way you'll have free graphs and charts of your stored data, and auto-refresh (based on an interval, not on events).

You also may take a look a Grafana, an event more specialized tool in storing / representing graphs of values.

But if you really want to store your data on MySQL, you may not want to use MySQL Workbench as a user interface, it's a developper tool to build your database. You may however build a graphical interface from scratch, and send it an event when you're updating your tables so it refreshes itself, but it's a lot of work that Kibana/Grafana does for you.